# Trim extra white space within column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have the following select that is converting a name from `Lastname, Firstname` format into `Firstname Lastname` format. It seems to be adding extra white space between the first name and the last name

```
SELECT substring(D.NAME, charindex(',', replace(D.NAME, ' ', '')) + 1, len(D.NAME)) 
        + ' ' 
        + left(D.NAME, charindex(',', D.NAME) -1) AS First_Last
FROM TEST_TABLE D
```

**Here are a few examples of the output I'm getting now:**

```
Johnnyyy            Smithsonnn
Kimmey       Test1
Denise          Stuffing
```

**Desired Format (single space between first and last name):**

```
Johnnyyy Smithsonnn
Kimmey Test1
Denise Stuffing
```

Comment: . . You should show what your sample data looks like.  That is probably the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there are names with or without `,` or with or without spaces after the `,`, or other inconsistencies. 
Anyway you can use `ltrim(rtrim())` before concatenating:

```
select 
  case 
    when d.name like '%,%' then
      ltrim(rtrim(substring(d.name, charindex(',', name) + 1, len(d.name))))
      + ' ' +
      ltrim(rtrim(left(D.NAME, charindex(',', d.name) -1))) 
    when d.name like '% %' then  
      ltrim(rtrim(substring(d.name, charindex(' ', name) + 1, len(d.name))))
      + ' ' +
      ltrim(rtrim(left(D.NAME, charindex(' ', d.name) -1))) 
    else ltrim(rtrim(d.name))
 end AS First_Last
```

Comment: I'm receiving an error, `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.`

Comment: This means that not all names contain `,`.

Comment: Yes that is true, I am seeing some names without commas

Comment: Still getting the `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function` error. I see there are some rows with a `,` than a space then name, and some with a `,` and no space, last name.

Comment: Is there a case where there is no comma and no space?

Comment: Yes, there are rows with name like this: `11000_606`

Answer (score 3):

I tend to like this technique.   In this example we use a rare replacement pattern of `†‡`, but you can use `<>` and `><`

Note: The outer `ltrim(rtrim( ... ))` is optional, I keep it as a "just in case".

**Example**

```
Select NewValue = ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace([Name],' ','†‡'),'‡†',''),'†‡',' ')))
 From  YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
NewValue
Johnnyyy Smithsonnn
Kimmey Test1
Denise Stuffing
```

Comment: Hello John, what does this do? '†‡'

Comment: @DxTx Replaces ANY number of repeating spaces with †‡.  This is the expansion phase.  Then we eliminate ‡† which will leave a SINGLE remainder of †‡ which is then replaced with a SPACE

Comment: I also use this method for normalizing spaces, though you can use a pair of guids in place of the special characters if you're worried about collisions.

Comment: @TimLehner Never thought about using guids... Not a bad idea for an absolute bullet proof approach

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select ltrim(rtrim(left(D.NAME, charindex(',', D.NAME, 0) - 1)))
  + ' ' 
  + ltrim(rtrim(right(D.NAME, len(D.NAME) - charindex(',', D.NAME, 0))))
from TEST_TABLE D
```

This worked on some test data I used below:

```
insert into #Test ([Name]) values ('Johnnyyy, Smithsonnn')
insert into #Test ([Name]) values ('Kimmey, Test1')
insert into #Test ([Name]) values ('Denise, Stuffing')
```

Which gives the intended result:

```
Johnnyyy Smithsonnn
Kimmey Test1
Denise Stuffing
```

Comment: I receive an error `Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`.

Comment: That's YOUR code just copied from your question? All I did was add ltrim(rtrim()) which trims the spaces from the front and the back of the string.

Comment: Yes rest of the code is the same that previously worked in my original post.

Comment: Please check my edited answer. I have tested this on my own data and it works. If you're getting an invalid length error then you must have some NAME values without a comma

Answer (score 0):

I think you intend to do the replace of spaces *after* extracting the name.  So:

```
SELECT (replace(left(D.NAME, charindex(',', D.NAME + ',') + 1), ' ', '') +
        ' ' +
        left(D.NAME, charindex(',', D.NAME + ',') - 1)
       ) AS First_Last
FROM TEST_TABLE D;
```

This also adds a comma for the `charindex()` so the comma is optional.

Comment: Error: `The replace function requires 3 argument(s).`

Comment: It seems to keep the last name first, following by the comma, and then has the First initial of the first name, followed by the last name (again). Here is an example: `Johnson,Amy` is being formatted as  `Johnson,A Johnson`  , instead of `Amy Johnson`